# Vuetify adds scrollbar when it's not needed

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I created a new project with vue-cli, then added vuetify with `vue add vuetify`. Opened the site and saw [a blank page with a useless scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stKDk.jpg)

I tried mounting app without actually `App` component, but the problem still exists. It vanishes only when I remove `import './plugins/vuetify'`

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import './plugins/vuetify'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: can you please show the code for `App.vue`?

Comment: You should mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just add the following to your css style :

```
html { overflow-y: auto }
```

This default behaviour of vuetify is explained here (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions/#scrollbar-overflow):

> Vuetify uses a slightly modified version of [ress reset](https://github.com/filipelinhares/ress)
> which by default turns on the html scrollbar to normalize behavior between browsers. This is a design choice and has been debated numerous times. There are pros and cons to having and not having it and as of now, the vote is in favor of leaving it as is. If you wish to disable this functionality, simply add `html { overflow-y: auto }` to your style file. Find more information on the [CSS Reset](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/css-reset/) page

Comment: I found it needed ```overflow-y: auto !important```

Comment: `.v-application--wrap {
  min-height: 100% !important;
}
` I needed this too.

Comment: don't forget to remove "scoped" property in style tag, I had to do that

Answer (score 13):

I have the same problem using vue-cli 3.8 + buefy.

Not the best solution, but here's the two ways I'm using :

#### Hide scrollbar globally

Scrollbar can be hidden by CSS style.

```html
<style>
html {
  overflow: hidden !important;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
</style>
```

#### Hide scrollbar in a specific views

I could hide scrollbar in a `home.vue` using DOM style.

```
<script>
  mounted: function() {
    let elHtml = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]
    elHtml.style.overflowY = 'hidden'
  },
  destroyed: function() {
    let elHtml = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]
    elHtml.style.overflowY = null
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is using the `overflow-hidden` class. You can even do `overflow-[x|y]-hidden` to be specific. I added it my main layout like `<Nuxt class="overflow-x-hidden"`.

Or without Nuxt, in `App.vue`: `<v-main class="overflow-hidden">`

Comment: That only adds that class to your `v-main` though, the issue is that Vuetify sets it on the html element.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following style worked for me

```
style="overflow: hidden;"
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) is a page that explains it