# How to modify Vuetify's auto-generated CSS

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

**What I'm Using**

Vuetify 2.5.6

**The Problem**

I'm trying to disable an odious scroll bar

[image]

But can't quite figure out how to destroy it (and its ilk). Every suggestion I've tried still yields a Vuetify auto-generated class "v-navigation-drawer__content" that has `overflow-y: auto;`.

I'd like to learn how to modify the default behavior of these Vuetify-generated CSS files (for this issue and for future ones).

**What I've Tried**

I've tried:

- adding `style="overflow: hidden;"` to the `v-navigation-bar` tag.
- modifying adding `.v-navigation-drawer__content { overflow: hidden !important }` to the style section in the view component.
- adding the following CSS and also adding mounted() and destroyed() hooks from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57128360/12397235)

**Minimal Reproducible Example**

```
<template>
    <v-navigation-drawer
        app
        clipped
        class="side-nav-bar"
        permanent>
        <v-menu
            bottom
            offset-y>
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">

                <v-list-item
                    two-line
                    v-bind="attrs"
                    v-on="on">
                    <v-list-item-avatar>
                        <v-img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/85.jpg"></v-img>
                    </v-list-item-avatar>
                    <v-list-item-content>
                        <v-list-item-title class="text-h6">Sandra Adams</v-list-item-title>
                        <v-list-item-subtitle>sandra_a88@gmail.com</v-list-item-subtitle>
                    </v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>

            </template>
            <v-list>
                <v-list-item
                    v-for="(workspace, i) in workspaces"
                    :key="i"
                    @click="changeWorkspaces(workspace)">
                    <v-list-item-title>{{ workspace.title  }}</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item>
                <v-divider />
                <v-list-item
                    @click="createNewWorkspace">
                    <v-list-item-title>Create Workspace</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
        </v-menu>

        <v-divider />

        <v-list
            nav
            dense
            v-for="(item, i) in sideNavOptions"
            :key="i">

                <v-list-item
                    v-if="!item.subList"
                    :key="item.title"
                    :to="item.link">
                    <v-list-item-icon>
                        <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
                    </v-list-item-icon>
                    <v-list-item-title class="title-bold">{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item>

                <v-list-group
                    v-else
                    :key="item.title"
                    :prepend-icon="item.icon"
                    no-action>
                    <template v-slot:activator>
                        <v-list-item>
                            <v-list-item-content>
                                <v-list-item-title class="title-bold">{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
                            </v-list-item-content>
                        </v-list-item>
                    </template>
                    <v-list-item
                        v-for="sublist in item.subList"
                        :to="sublist.link"
                        :key="sublist.title">
                        <v-list-item-title>{{ sublist.title }}</v-list-item-title>
                    </v-list-item>
                </v-list-group>

        </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "SideNavBar",
    data() {
        return {
            workspaces: [],
            sideNavOptions:[
                { title: "Dashboard", icon: "mdi-monitor-dashboard", link: "/dashboard" },
                {
                    title: "Workflow",
                    icon: "mdi-cog",
                    subList: [
                        { title: "Inbox", link: "/workflows/inbox" },
                        { title: "Action Required", link: "/workflows/action_required" },
                        { title: "Waiting for Others", link: "/workflows/waiting_for_others" },
                        { title: "Approved", link: "/workflows/approved" },
                        { title: "Sent", link: "/workflows/sent" },
                        { title: "Completed", link: "/workflows/completed" },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    title: "Templates",
                    icon: "mdi-cog",
                    subList: [
                        { title: "Placeholder", link: "/templates/placeholder" }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    title: "Contacts",
                    icon: "mdi-cog",
                    subList: [
                        { title: "Placeholder", link: "/contacts/placeholder" }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    title: "Settings",
                    icon: "mdi-cog",
                    subList: [
                        { title: "Workspace Settings", link: "/settings/workspace" },
                        { title: "Company Settings", link: "/settings/company" },
                        { title: "Department Settings", link: "/settings/department" }
                    ]
                },
                { title: "Reminders", icon: "mdi-cog", link: "/reminders" }
            ]
        }
    },
    async beforeMount() {
        await this.getUserWorkspaces()
    },
    methods: {
        changeWorkspaces(workspace) {
            console.log(workspace)
        },
        createNewWorkspace() {
            console.log("Creating new workspace")
        },
        async getUserWorkspaces() {
            console.log("Getting user workspaces")
            this.workspaces = [ { title: "Placeholder_1" }, { title: "Placeholder_2" } ]
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="sass" scoped>
.side-nav-bar {
    overflow: hidden !important;
    color: $white !important;
    background: $light_gray !important;
}

.v-navigation-drawer.v-navigation-drawer__content {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
</style>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You should not modify generated code, you need to append CSS classes or styles into your component. Please, create a minimal reproducible example or at least post your code.

Comment: @dreamwalker I already tried that, as mentioned in the question. And my query was poorly worded: I don't want to modify the auto-generated code after it has been generated, I want to modify the generator so that it doesn't make the code I don't need. I'll add a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `.v-navigation-drawer__content { overflow: hidden !important }` should work but it's not working, because you are trying to change the style of a component which not a part of your current component using `scoped css`.

Try to remove `scoped` from your `<style>` and it will work. I usually create a global stylesheet and add it in `App.vue` file and make changes in that file.

Read more [here](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#mixing-local-and-global-styles) about the `scoped` feature.